# Need help in locating "Laptops & Desktops" and "Laptops" elements on flipkart website--selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, relative-path

Need help in locating "Laptops & Desktops" and "Laptops" elements on flipkart website--selenium[image]

Answer (score 0):

For "Laptop and Desktop" this xpath:

```
//a[text()='Laptop and Desktop']
```

For "Laptops" this xpath:

```
//div[@class='_3XS_gI']//a[text()='Laptops']
```